# Selecting data cuts off labels in Altair plot

Tags: altair

I have an Altair Chart similar to the one produced by the code below. Before selecting any data, I can see labels for `x` and `t` on the line plot (the first image below). However, after selecting data, numbers appear on the axes and push out the labels (the second image below). How can I keep the labels from being cut off? In my actual problem, the scales for the x- and y-axes can vary substantially between selections, so it is not an option to use scale for all possible selections.

```
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_freq = 5
n_data = 1000

freqs = np.arange(1, n_freq + 1)
df_freq = pd.DataFrame({'f': freqs})
df_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'f': np.repeat(a=freqs, repeats=n_data),
    't': np.tile(A=np.linspace(0, 2, n_data), reps=n_freq),
})
df_data['x'] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * df_data['f'] * df_data['t'])

freq_selection = alt.selection_single(
    fields=('f',),
    empty='none',
    on='mouseover',
    nearest=True,
    clear='mouseout',
) 
freq_table = alt.Chart(df_freq).mark_text().encode(
    y=alt.Y(shorthand='f:Q', axis=None, scale=alt.Scale(domain=(0, n_freq + 1))),
    text='f:N',
).add_selection(freq_selection)
data_plot = alt.Chart(df_data).mark_line().encode(
    x='t:Q',
    y='x:Q',
).transform_filter(freq_selection)

alt.hconcat(freq_table, data_plot, spacing=100).properties(padding=100)
```

Before making a selection:

[image: Before Selection]

After making a selection:

[image: After Selection]

Answer (score 1):

The vega-lite renderer chooses axis limits either via the extent of displayed data, or via explicit scale domains. If there is no displayed data and no scale domain, the axis is empty.

Since you don't want to set the scale domain directly, one way to address this is to create some invisible data that define the "default" domain, and layer this on your chart. For example:

```python
background = alt.Chart(
    {"values": [{"t": 0, "x": 0}, {"t": 1, "x": 1}]}
).mark_point(opacity=0).encode(
    x='t:Q',
    y='x:Q'
)

alt.hconcat(freq_table, background + data_plot, spacing=100).properties(padding=100)
```

[image]

Notice that the empty chart now has axis domains based on the limits of this transparent data.